# Is there a way to see the accepted answer first as was the case in the past?

Tags: support, sorting

We now have a drop-down menu for choosing how to order answers. What I can't find is a way to have them as in the past - accepted, then by score.

Is there still a way to see answers like that?

This is **NOT** a question of which is better. This is a simple question of whether this functionality still exists (and if so - where) or was it removed.

Comment: Not with built-in functionality, though I'm pretty sure there's a userscript for that.

Comment: @RyanM Thanks. You can transform your comment into an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Have you also posted a feature request for this option to be available on the menu?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a [user script written by Glorfindel available on Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/9144/accepted-answer-pinner) that does this: Accepted Answer Pinner.

See Glorfindel's [original announcement post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369579) under the MSE announcement for the change.